# Need a secure method to connect to my home computer from work (Windows connecting to OpenSuse)

Tags: linux, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I need to be able to log into (with X enabled) my home computer (running OpenSuse 11.4) from my work computer (running Windows XP). I was originally going to setup ssh on my home computer but then realized that I wouldn't be able to get my desktop this way.

At work, we use windows remote desktop connection to log into other computers within our network, but I'm planning on asking my manager if I'm allowed to login to my home computer. If he accepts, I need a method to actually make it happen.

I looked at FreeNX which seemed awesome but it doesn't seem to have windows support.

Whatever the solution, I need it to be VERY secure. To an extent that I would like to only allow my work IP to be allowed to even try an login.

Anyone ever had the same issue? Ideas? The bridge to cross here is the fact that I'm connecting from windows. Also, would I need to ask our sys admins to open any ports for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VNC would definitely be the way to go, because there are servers and clients available for all platforms. You'll need to forward a port at home if your computer is behind NAT, but nothing will be necessary on the connecting side. I'm not very familiar with the Linux server options, but I'm sure you can configure a blacklist/whitelist for connections.